# Excel - Random Sampling

Tags: excel, random, sample

I have a list of names and a separate table of with Monday to Friday with percentages next to each total which in total equal to 100%.

So Monday is 30%, how I do make sure 30% of that list is Monday, 20% for Tuesday etc.

I've tried using the formulas in the link below but it just returns Monday for each row
https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4486-excel-random-with-probability.html

The first Table

```
Monday 30%
Tuesday 20%
Wednesday50%
```

Second List which has a,b,c and the next column is what I want to return the above based on the percentage.  So from a list of 10 Wednesday should appear 5 times.

```
A - Monday
B - Monday
C - Wednesday
D - Wednesday
E - Tuesday
F - Wednesday
G - Wednesday
H - Tuesday
I - Wednesday
J - Monday
```

Comment: This is a bit hard to follow - could you show us some sample data please with expected results? Plz see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Thanks for responding Tom, I've added a few tables to clarify.

Comment: Ah, much easier for me to understand, thank you. Now the question is, do you need Wednesday to occur _exactly_ (I think you mean) 5 times, or would it be subject to random variation and occur maybe 4 or 6 times in different samples?

Comment: I put 10 to keep it simple but my rows are 900. Appear even close to 50% of the time

Answer (score 0):

The formula in the link works OK for me - I just had to change the ranges appropriately:

```
=INDEX(A$2:A$4,COUNTIF(C$2:C$4,"<="&RAND())+1)
```

As predicted, you only get 5 Wednesdays, 3Mondays and 2 Tuesdays as a long-term average. This is a typical run:

[image]

If you have Excel 365, you can now do this with a spill formula:

```
=INDEX(A2:A4,COUNTIF(C2:C4,"<="&RANDARRAY(COUNTA(F:F)-1))+1)
```

Comment: That has worked, thanks and I wasn't aware of spill formula but have weekend to read more about it.